# Referencing a file (forward slash path) from Windows is giving error while the same works for Linux

Tags: linux, windows, android-studio, gradle, filepath

I have a gradle file which references another gradle file using:

```
// settings.gradle

// references `playground-include-settings.gradle` file

apply from: "../playground-common/playground-include-settings.gradle"
```

When opening the code in Android Studio, the above Gradle file is executed and with the same exact setup, it works for Linux but DO NOT work when done for Windows.

I tried with backward slash `\\`, double forward slash `//` in Windows but it did not work either.

Error (ONLY on WINDOWS): (Line 19 is above of apply from ...)

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script. at settings_b5vpkybm1b8f1fi4z6dnydgh9.run(D:\path\to\code\settings.gradle:19)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

What is the cause of the error and how to make referencing another file compatible in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was not related to file path, but rather I missed the error stack trace that said to use "JDK 11" instead of "JDK 8"

I had to go to Project Structure dialog in Android Studio and then under SDK Location, set the JDK to 11 version.

And then Gradle sync. It worked.